# matplotlib plot pdf error with polar coordinate

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, pdf-generation, polar-coordinates

I would like to plot and save as pdf this:

[image]

This is what I have done so far:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
plt.rc('font', family='sans',size=24)
matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)
matplotlib.rc('legend', fontsize=24) 
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\boldmath']

fnameout = 'test'

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 6))
G = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 3)

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.08, right=0.94, top=0.94, bottom=0.08, 
                    wspace=0.24,hspace=0.14)  

axes_1 = plt.subplot(G[0, 0:2])

axes_2 = plt.subplot(G[0, 2],projection='polar')

formatf = 'png'
fname_output = './OUTPUT/'+fnameout
fig.savefig(fname_output+'.'+formatf,format=formatf,
                   bbox_inches='tight')
```

The problem is this. If I plot in png format I have no problem a all. However, if I try to plot in pdf format. I get the following error:

```
KeyError: b'tcrm2488'
```

I have no problem if I plot in standard coordinate system x-y or I remove "latex" formatting.

Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Python 3.8, matplotlib 3.3.3.

Comment: Python 3.8.5, matplotlib 3.1.2. Version problem?